# Does XmlPullParser need special treatment for 2.3.3 and older Android versions?

Tags: android, xml-parsing, android-2.2-froyo, android-2.3-gingerbread, xmlpullparser

I am pulling the content from the remote XML file via `XmlPullParser` using code like this:

```
    factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
    factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
    parser = factory.newPullParser();
    parser.setInput(xml, "UTF-8");

    eventType = parser.getEventType();

    // process tag while not reaching the end of document
    while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
        switch (eventType) {
            // at start of document: START_DOCUMENT
            case XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT:
                break;
            // at start of a tag: START_TAG
            case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                //get tag name
                String tagName = parser.getName();
                if (tagName.equalsIgnoreCase("item")) {
                    listObject = new MyClass();
                } else if (tagName.equalsIgnoreCase("yy")) {
                    listObject.setYY(parser.nextText());
                } else if (tagName.equalsIgnoreCase("zz")) {
                    listObject.setZZ(parser.nextText());
                } 
                break;
        }
        // jump to next event
        eventType = parser.next();
```

As you can see, there is nothing new or odd in this code.

Now, when the fetched XML content comes to this parser on Android 3.0 and newer systems, they look "normal", like on this image:

[image]

You can see that the content of XML file has been properly fetched.

**But when I connect the same project to Android 2.3.3 or older devices**, I get a **DIFFERENT** result! Look at the same image taken on Android 2.2 device.

[image]

You see these odd characters `\uoooo`! Also `buffer` item has been changed to `txtBuf`!

What does all this mean? Why is this happening in Android 2.3.3 downwards and how to solve this issue? This breaks my parser and kills my app.

Comment: Are you sure that the unparsed content comes the same on pre and post 2.3 ?

Comment: @Alex The first one is on Android 4.0.3, and the later one is on Android 2.2. Last night I checked on Android 2.3.3 and it was the same as on Android 2.2. I am at my wits' end. I can't figure our what is causing it?! PullParser, server or something else?

Comment: Maybe it will help if you parse the same file but placed locally in the asset, just to make sure it's not a http problem

Comment: @Alex I also noticed that the URL for XML file does not end up with file.xml, but with file.ashx. This is probably a ASP.NET server script which generates XML. Is this causing a problem?

Comment: @Alex It PARSES locally WITHOUT any problems. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Modify your parsing:

```
XmlPullParser xpp = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance().newPullParser();
xpp.setInput(xml, "UTF-8");

while (xpp.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT)
{
    if (xpp.getEventType() == XmlPullParser.START_TAG)
    {
        if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("item"))
        {
            listObject = new MyClass();
        }
        else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("yy"))
        {
            listObject.setYY(parser.nextText());
        }
        else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("zz"))
        {
            listObject.setZZ(parser.nextText());
        }
    }
    else if(xpp.getEventType() == XmlPullParser.END_TAG)
    {
        listObject = null;
    }
    xpp.next();
}
```

Comment: Hm what exactly did you do here? It seems that you took out namespace awareness and better handled the flaw.